# Scanf to check reading of integer doesn't work

Tags: c, input, int, scanf

I'm testing the scanf function to check whether or not it has read in one value (an integer) according to the user input. In my netbeans IDE, the program compiles but upon entering a value of x like '6' nothing happens, until it is entered again, then the program proceeds to react correctly, printing the first if statement. Any help on this issue would be much appreciated:

Again here is a snippet:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("please enter a value for x");
    scanf("%d",&x);

    if(scanf("%d",&x) == 1) // checks to see if it contains one value
        printf("x value has one value");

    else
        printf("X value is not an integer or has more than one value");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have two `scanf`s in your code(One before the `if` and the other in the `if(...)`). When you enter `6`,the first `scanf` takes it up and then the second `scanf` inside the `if(...)` waits for the next input making you enter twice.

Remove the first `scanf` and your program will work fine!

Comment: Cheers mate, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Well... the first scanf() stops and waits for you to type in '6' and then press Enter.  And then you've got it performing another scanf() which will repeat that behavior.

Just drop the first time completely and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading in two values. Each time you call `scanf`, the program will wait until you input something. Since you call `scanf` twice, (once before the if statement, and once in the if statement), you're waiting to read in two values. Use something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int x;
    printf("please enter a value for x");
    int valueCount = scanf("%d", &x);

    if (valueCount == 1) // checks to see if it contains one value
        printf("x value has one value");
    else
        printf("X value is not an integer or has more than one value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` returns the number of items matched, or EOF.  But it also wants input every time it is called.  So you need to capture the return value of the first statement, instead of calling it again.

That is, replace `scanf(...)` with `int retval = scanf(...)`.

Then the `if(...)` statement should read `if(retval == 1)...`.